# using iTunes lookup with apps that are not on the store yet

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, itunes

I am using the URL

```
http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.myCompany.myApp
```

to get a JSON file with the information about my app. This works if the app is already published on the App Store but I am still developing it and the result coming from that URL contains just this:

```
{
 "resultCount":0,
 "results": []
}
```

I have tried to use

```
http://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.myCompany.myApp
```

and

```
https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.myCompany.myApp
```

and I receive

> Http/1.1 Service Unavailable

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do that. I'd suggest using another way to get the data you need or mocking the response you expect while the app isn't available and forward the request to Apple as soon as data is available.

Comment: I was suspecting that. THANKS